# Apache: Waiting for Child Process - WTF?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, process

I run a PHP script, something goes wrong (I haven't figured out what yet). Just to have a fresh start. I restart apache, but in the logs I get this:

```
[Fri Dec 25 21:27:16 2009] [notice] Child 7584: Child process is running
[Fri Dec 25 21:27:16 2009] [notice] Child 7584: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Dec 25 21:27:16 2009] [notice] Child 7584: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Dec 25 21:27:16 2009] [notice] Child 7584: Starting thread to listen on port 9090.
[Fri Dec 25 21:27:30 2009] [notice] Child 10048: Waiting 180 more seconds for 6 worker threads to finish.
```

Firstly, what is the above and what does it mean?

Secondly, how do I get apache to restart properly without waiting for any child process. I ask this because, I find that some of the new php runs I do, just hang and I am guessing apache/php is wating for what ever was running before?

Thanks all, I really appreciate help on the above.

Answer (score 1):

I think this belongs on serverfault, but anyway:

The log messages sound like you are using mpm_worker. This is probably not a good idea if you load mod_php.

Try switching to mpm_prefork and see what happens.